# Third order nonlinear ODE

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking to solve the following third order nonlinear ODE:

$$\frac{\textrm{d}^{3}y}{\textrm{d}x^{3}}+\biggl(\frac{\textrm{d}y}{\textrm{d}x}\biggr)^{2}-y\frac{\textrm{d}^{2}y}{\textrm{d}x^{2}}=0,$$

subject to

$$y(x=0)=0,\qquad\frac{\textrm{d}y}{\textrm{d}x}(x=0)=-1,\qquad\frac{\textrm{d}y}{\textrm{d}x}(x\to\infty)\to0.$$

From inspection I can see that the solution is $y(x)=e^{-x}-1$. However, I would like to be able to derive this solution for myself. I've made a couple of attempts that so far have proved unsuccessful. For example, if I set $z=\textrm{d}y/\textrm{d}x$ then

\begin{align*}
\frac{\textrm{d}^{2}y}{\textrm{d}x^{2}}&=z\frac{\textrm{d}z}{\textrm{d}y},
\\
\frac{\textrm{d}^{3}y}{\textrm{d}x^{3}}&=z\biggl(\frac{\textrm{d}z}{\textrm{d}y}\biggr)^{2}+z^{2}\frac{\textrm{d}^{2}z}{\textrm{d}y^{2}}.
\end{align*}

So that

$$z\biggl(\frac{\textrm{d}z}{\textrm{d}y}\biggr)^{2}+z^{2}\frac{\textrm{d}^{2}z}{\textrm{d}y^{2}}+z^{2}-yz\frac{\textrm{d}z}{\textrm{d}y}=0.$$

The above could be rewritten like so

$$\frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}y}\biggl(z\frac{\textrm{d}z}{\textrm{d}y}\biggr)+z-y\frac{\textrm{d}z}{\textrm{d}y}=0,$$

which is equivalent to

$$\frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}y}\biggl(z\frac{\textrm{d}z}{\textrm{d}y}\biggr)+z^{2}\frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}y}\biggl(\frac{y}{z}\biggr)=0.$$

Any suggestions as to where to go from here or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Thanks

Comment: $$y'''=yy''-(y')^2$$

Divide everything by $y^2$. Then by the identity
$$
\left(\dfrac{y'}y\right)'=\dfrac{y''y-(y')^2}{y^2}
$$
we have

$$\frac{y'''}{y^2}=\left(\dfrac{y'}y\right)'$$

I'm not sure what to do with the LHS after this (I could integrate by parts, but that doesn't seem to make the problem easier).

Comment: Yours ODE can be reduced to Abel equations of the First Kind,but closed-form probably not exist. Only with numerics can be solved. Solution looks like: $y(x)\approx 14.9669\, -15.9711 \text{erf}\left(1.3159\, +0.3067 x-0.0184 x^2\right)$

Comment: This looks like the [chazy equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chazy_equation) and this question has a [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2049674/chazy-equation-and-movable-singularity), there is a difference in the coefficients so they are not exactly equals but should be similar I think at least but I barely get the idea about about how is solved, there is also a comment with a link to a pdf that looks useful too.

Comment: @ManojKumar as far as I can see $y(x)=e^{-x}-1$, is a solution of the ODE. It seems strange, to me at least, that it is so difficult to derive such a simple solution.

Comment: @Juggler Yes you are right, I made a silly mistake in substitution.

Comment: @Juggler This is the reason why I am struggling yet with this equation.

Comment: if you know such a simple solution, then why not make the suggestive substitution $z = e^x(y+1)?$

Answer (score 4):

THIS NOTE MAY HELP

We want to solve
$$
y'''+(y')^2-yy''=0\tag 1
$$
Instead of (1) I will solve
$$
y'''-(y')^2-yy''=0\tag 2
$$
We have
$$
y'''-(y')^2-yy''=0\Leftrightarrow y'''-(yy')'=0\Leftrightarrow y''-yy'=-C_1\Leftrightarrow
$$
$$
(y'-\frac{y^2}{2})'=(-C_1x)'\Leftrightarrow y'-y^2/2=-C_1x-C_2
$$
If we set $y=-2u'/u$ we arrive to
$$
u''=\frac{1}{2}(C_1x+C_2)u
$$ 
The last equation is solvable with Airy $\textrm{Ai}(x)$,$\textrm{Bi}(x)$ functions see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function). 
$$
y(x)=-2^{2/3}C_1^{1/3}\frac{\textrm{Bi}'\left(\frac{C_1x+C_2}{2^{1/3}C_1^{2/3}}\right)+\textrm{Ai}'\left(\frac{C_1x+C_2}{2^{1/3}C_1^{2/3}}\right)C_3}{\textrm{Bi}\left(\frac{C_1x+C_2}{2^{1/3}C_1^{2/3}}\right)+\textrm{Ai}\left(\frac{C_1x+C_2}{2^{1/3}C_1^{2/3}}\right)C_3}
$$
For the conditions $y(0)=0$, $y'(0)=-1$, $y'(\infty)=0$, we easily get  $C_1=1/2$,$C_2=1$,$C_3=-\textrm{Bi}'(2^{1/3})/\textrm{Ai}'(2^{1/3})$.

Comment: Unfortunately the sign in (1) makes huge difference...

Comment: Could you explain further or give another hint about how you got that solution?

Comment: Thanks I got it now, +1

Comment: In this case, the solution for $y(x)$ has another really simple form: $y(x)=-\tanh(x/2)$.

Comment: @Juggler. The function $-\tanh(x/2)$ does not satisfies the initial conditions.

Comment: @Juggler. However its a good thought.

Comment: @NikosBagis I think $y(x)=-\tanh(x/2)$ satisifies all the BCs.

Comment: @Juggler. $y(x)=-\tanh(x/2)\Rightarrow y'(x)=-\frac{1}{\cosh^2(x/2)}$. Hence $y'(0)=-1/2$.

Comment: @NikosBagis $y'(0)=-\frac{1}{\cosh^{2}(0/2)}=-1$.

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution to the ODE, but it does not fit all initial conditions.

Ignoring initial conditions, a solution to this ODE is $$y=\frac{-6c}{cx+d}. $$

**How I found this solution:**
We have $y'''=yy''-(y')^2$. By induction, we can prove
$$y^{(2n)}=\sum_{r=0}^{n}b_r^{2n}y^{(r)}y^{(2n-1-r)}$$
and $$y^{(2n+1)}=\sum_{r=0}^{n}b_r^{2n+1}y^{(r)}y^{(2n-r)}.$$
Now let $n=1$, (I know that it is not true, but it helps to find a solution.) we have
$$y''=b_0^{2}yy'+b_1^{2}yy'=(b_0^{2}+b_1^{2})yy'=\frac{b_0^{2}+b_1^{2}}{2}(y^2)'$$
which has the solution of the form
$$y=\frac{a}{cx+d}. $$
Plugging this $y$ in the ODE, shows that $a=-6c$.

Comment: +1 You could rewrite it as $y=-\frac{6}{x+a}$. Pity it doesn't fit the initial conditions;)

Answer (score 3):

Here is also my note (unfortunately, probably also not super helpful).

$$y'''+(y')^2-yy''=0\quad\quad(1)$$
Can be rewritten as:
$$y'''=y^2\left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)'$$.

Integrating both sides (using integration by parts), this leads to:

$$y''=yy'-2\int(y')^2dx + C.$$
Thus, $$2\int(y')^2dx=yy'-y''+C=\left(\frac{y^2}{2}\right)'-y''+C=\left(\frac{y^2}{2}-y'\right)'+C.\quad\quad(2)$$
Thus the differential equation is also equal to:
$$\int \left(y'\right)^2dx = \left(\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)^2-\frac{y'}{2}\right)'+C$$

From this point on, the derivation gets somehow fishy, but if we assume that the integral $\int (y')^2dx$ is zero (or a constant) (but of course, I don't know why this should be the case), we arrive to a differential equation
$$\left(\frac{y^2}{2}-y'\right)'=-C,$$
which has a solution
$y(x)=ae^x+be^{-x}-C$. Plugging in the initial conditions, we get $a=0, b=-1, C = 1$ as we guessed at the first place.

But I hope someone will come up with a better solution:)

Comment: When replacing $y(x)=ae^x+be^{-x}+C$ in $(\frac{y^2}{2}-y')'=yy'-y''$ it doesn't gives $C$ and $\int \left(y'\right)^2dx =C=-1$ is not possible but I like this approach because if the integral stays positive it sounds like conservation of energy ($\int m\dot{r}^2 dt=E$) which could make sense in a physical system +1

Comment: @dandide Yes. That would be also my thinking. Maybe approximate the integral with some other "conservation" would lead to some solvable equation.

Answer (score 1):

THIS NOTE MAY (NOT) HELP

$y'''-y'=0\rightarrow y=Ae^x+Be^{-x}+Ce^{0x}\rightarrow_{B.C} A=0,B=1,C=-1$ so this equation determines uniquely that $y=e^x-1$ but it also solves $(y^{(6)}-y^{(4)})+(y'''+(y')^2-yy'')=0$ for example so it lives in the space of solution of this last equations but it is not clear it belong to the basis of that space.

Instead of solving $y'''-y'=0$ directly one could use it to reduce the other equation, 
$$0=(y^{(6)}-y^{(4)})+(y'''+(y')^2-yy'')$$

$$\rightarrow_{[y'''=y'\Rightarrow y^{(6)}=y^{(4)}]} 0=y'''+(y')^2-yy'' \quad\text{(our equation)}$$

$$\rightarrow_{\frac{d}{dx}}0=y''''+y'y''-yy'''$$

$$\rightarrow_{[y'''=y'\Rightarrow y''''=y'' \text{ & } y''=y+D]}0=(y+D)+y'(y+D)-y(y')=Dy'+y+D=De^{-\frac{x}{D}}(e^{\frac{x}{D}}y)'+D$$

$$\rightarrow y=Fe^{-\frac{x}{D}}-D$$

$$\rightarrow_{BC\Rightarrow F=1,D=1} y=e^{-x}-1$$

And we get the same solution again anyway, so $y'''-y'=0$ helps obtain a solution but it doesn't really helps us solve the original equation $0=y'''+(y')^2-yy''$ (or $0=(y^{(6)}-y^{(4)})+(y'''+(y')^2-yy'')$)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the suggestions. Some interesting ideas.

I noticed that making the substitution $z=(\textrm{d}y/\textrm{d}x)^{2}$, gives the following

$$\frac{\textrm{d}^{2}z}{\textrm{d}y^{2}}+4z\frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}y}\biggl(\frac{y}{2\sqrt{z}}\biggr)=0.$$

Not really sure that helps though...

Answer (score 0):

Here would be my solution. We start with the equation $$y'''+(y')^2-yy''=0.$$
Then, if we differentiate it twice we get $$y^{(5)}+(y'')^2-yy^{(4)}=0$$
which is intriguingly similar.
Now, one of the solution (unique?) would be if the set of equations simultaneously hold, i.e.,

$$y^{(5)}=y''' \tag{1}$$
$$y'' = y'\quad\text{or}\quad y''=-y'\tag{2}$$
$$y^{(4)}=y''\tag{3}$$

General solutions of the differential equations:
$$(1):\quad y(x)=a_1x^2+b_1x+c_1e^x+d_1e^{-x}+f_1$$
$$(2):\quad y(x)=a_2e^x+b_2\quad\text{or}\quad y(x)=a_2e^{-x}+b_b$$
$$(3):\quad y(x)=a_3x+b_3e^x+c_3e^{-x}+d_3$$

Plugging the initial conditions into $(1)$:

$$y(0)=0\ \to \ c_1+d_1+f_1=0\\
y'(0)=-1\ \to \ b_1+c_1-d_1=-1\\
y'(\infty)=0\ \to \ a_1=b_1=c_1=0,\ \text{and}\ d_1\ \text{is any number},$$
and thus $a_1=0, b_1=0, c_1=0,d_1=1,f_1=-1, $ leading to a unique solution $$y(x)=e^{-x}-1.$$
We now have to check if that solution holds also for equations $(2)$ and $(3)$. But that holds obviously for the right constants.